# how the arguments are being sorted in this function?

Tags: c, arguments, argv, argc

sorry for not so-specific and not so-pro question , this code will sort any given parameters in lexicographic order, but it's still a little bit vague to me, if you have a little bit of time and patience and you could clarify step by step what's going on inside+ code I would be very thankful.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i;
    int j;

    while (argc > 1)
    {
        j = 0;
        i = 0;
        while (++i < argc)
            if (j == 0 || strcmp(argv[i], argv[j]) < 0)
                j = i;
        while (*argv[j])
            putchar(*argv[j]++);
        putchar('\n');
        if (j != --argc)
            swap(argv + j, argv + argc);
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to *debug* it? Either by using [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging), or using an actual debugger to step through the code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values? Doing both, together with pen and paper to write down everything, should be helpful.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude is there any good debugger you recommend ?

Comment: Question, Suggest reviewing `while (*argv[j])  putchar(*argv[j]++);`. What is being incremented here?